# Linux user is added to a group - Group permission for a dir is rwx - Still user is not able to create a dir in that permitted dir,

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
    user@user-ubuntu:/usr/workspace$ whoami
user
user@user-ubuntu:/usr/workspace$ sudo ls -ltrah .
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4.0K Sep  2 20:10 ..
drwxrwx---  2 root fooo 4.0K Sep  9 13:28 .
user@user-ubuntu:/usr/workspace$ git clone https://github.com/nkrishnawat/fooo-backend.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'fooo-backend': Permission denied



less /etc/groups -tail
nvidia-persistenced:x:137:
citrixlog:x:1001:
fooo:x:1002:user
```

Comment: Has the user logged out and back in since the account was added to the group?

Comment: Dont permission work instantaneously ? I have never seen logout/logback for permissions.

Comment: Also I am not sure why I am getting authentication failure for:user@user-ubuntu:/usr/workspace/fooo-backend$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

Comment: Permissions on a filesystem change immediately, yes.  But the group membership of running processes (like the user's shell) don't necessarily change as soon as the `/etc/group` file is changed.

Comment: The `su` command prompts for the password of the account whose permissions you are requesting (in this case, the `root` password).  Are you entering the `root` password or your own account password?  `sudo` is the command that prompts you for your account password in order to gain another account's privileges.

Comment: wrt, root access: I was able to change root password: sudo -i
passwd

Comment: How do I log out/login, You mean log out of system, of terminte the shell and open new terminal ?

Comment: Completely log out of the system, @user204069

Comment: @SottoVoce, the group memberships of running processes don't change through the modification of some file, period.

Comment: @ikkachu I'm not sure what statement of mine you're contradicting.

Answer (score 1):

You report that when `user` attempts
`$ mkdir /usr/workspace/baz` they are greeted
with "Permission denied".

If you run `$ id` you will notice that group "fooo"
does not appear in the output.
The contents of /etc/group are consulted at login time,
and will contribute to that `id` output.

Log out, log back in, verify the `id` output looks good,
and attempt the `mkdir` once more, seeing it succeed.